# SPFx Solution has a warning stopping production builds has anyone seen it before?

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, gulp, webpack, warning

I have been supporting an SPFx solution and I am required to make a small change however it will no longer build.

I have tried pulling the last version back down from our repository but it has the same issue, has anyone seen this before or knows how to resolve it?

[image: Build error]

Comment: Have you used `loader-set-webpack-public-path` anywhere in your package? Try running `npm i @microsoft/loader-set-webpack-public-path` in your package.

Comment: @Ganesh I have added the npm package you mentioned but it has not changed anything. I have added an require to it in the main JS file with no change, and to the gulpfile.js which cases an error. Any suggestion of how to proceed?